# A probability problem with sequences

Tags: probability, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, recurrence-relations

> Choose at random the distinct numbers $a,b$ from the set $\{1,2,\ldots,10\}$. With them, define the sequence $(x_n)_{n \ge 1}$ such that $x_1=x_2=1$ and $x_{n+2}=ax_{n+1}-bx_n$. What is the probability that for the choice made the sequence $x_n$ would converge?

I think that if $b=a-1$ the sequence converges, but I do not know for the other cases if it is or not.

Comment: Notice: Nice answers can be accepted. Have you tried something else? It seems not much to me so far.

Comment: You have 11 questions, and only one has an accepted answer. It would be nice to accept the answers to your questions that worked for you...

Comment: I thought I did that. I am sorry and I am going to do that right now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**HINT**

You sequence obeys the recurrence relation $x_{n+2} - ax_{n+1} - bx_n = 0$, which has a characteristic equation $r^2-ar-b=0$ with solutions
$$
r_\pm = \frac{a \pm \sqrt{a^2+4b}}{2},
$$
which would imply your sequence is given by $x_n = Cr_+^n + Kr_-^n$. For what values of $r_\pm$ will this converge? Can you translate this to $a,b$ instead of $r_\pm$?

---

**UPDATE**

So $x_n$ will converge iff $|r_+| < 1$ and $|r_-|<1$ at the same time.

Comment: I made the calculus with the given gormula and the exponents and got that the probability would be 0 , 0,1 or 0.5 or 0.09 and I do not know if I had more cases somewhere. Is one of these answers corect?

Comment: I gor to this relationship: $(a+sqrt(a^2+4b))/2)^2(c^2-c)+(a-sqrt(a^2+4b))/2)^2(k^2-k)-2ckb-0

Comment: @user fixed, next time please edit directly.

Comment: @mathgirl see another update...

Answer (score 3):

$x_1, x_2$ are integers, as well as $a$ and $b$. That means that all $x_n, n=1,2,\ldots$ are integers. A sequence of integers converges if and only if it is eventually constant.

So if $L$ is the assumed limit, there exist an $N$ such that $x_n=L\; \forall n\ge N$. That means

$$L = x_{N+2}=ax_{N+1} - bx_N = aL-bL=(a-b)L \Longrightarrow 0=(a-b-1)L.$$

That means $L=0$ or $a=b+1$.

If $a=b+1$, then the recursion forumla becomes

$$x_{n+2}=ax_{n+1} - bx_n=(b+1)x_{n+1} - bx_n,$$

which means $x_3=(b+1)-b=1$ and thus all the $x_n$ are $1$ (the recursion depends only on the last 2 sequence elements), so the seqeunce is constant and thus converging.

OTOH, $L=0$ would imply there is a greatest index $M$ such that $x_M \neq 0$ (existing, as $x_1=x_2 \neq 0$).

But then we would have

$$0=x_{M+2}=ax_{M+1} - bx_M = a\cdot0 -bx_M = -bx_M,$$

which is impossible as $b \in \{1,\ldots,10\}$ and $x_M \neq 0$ also. That means $L=0$ is not possible, and the cases where $a=b+1$ are **exactly** the ones where the sequence converges (by being constantly $1$).

Comment: +1, very clever observation